# Using express-validator typescript definitions

Tags: node.js, express, typescript

I'm trying to convert some of my code to TypeScript, but having problems with express-validator definitions

My code looks like this:

```
///<reference path='../../../d.ts/node.d.ts' />
///<reference path='../../../d.ts/express.d.ts' />
///<reference path='../../../d.ts/express-validator.d.ts' />
import express = require('express');
import validator = require('express-validator');

function validate(req: express.Request, res: express.Response) {
    req.assert('name', 'Name is required').notEmpty();
    var errors = req.validationErrors();

    if (errors !== null && errors.length > 0) {
        res.json({
            result: false,
            errors: errors
        });
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Typescript compiler generates following errors:

```
error TS2094: The property 'assert' does not exist on value of type 'express.Request'.
error TS2094: The property 'validationErrors' does not exist on value of type 'express.Request'.
```

Which makes sense especially looking at the expreess-validator definition

```
export interface RequestValidation {
    check(field: string, message: string): Validator;
    assert(field: string, message: string): Validator;
    sanitize(field: string): Sanitizer;
    onValidationError(func: (msg: string) => void): void;
}
```

My understandment of RequestValidation interface is it must extend express.Request interface, but modifying this interface declaration does not really help.

I'm I doing something wrong?

Thank You!

Comment: I've never used express, but from the definition files it looks like Request does not have the `assert` method. `RequestValidation` does not extend `Request`, but even if it did it would make no difference (as you wrote yourself) because your method (`validate`) receives a `Request` and not a `RequestValidation`

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like the Express Validator library extends the Express `Request` object. i.e. it adds additional methods to the existing `Request` defined in Express.

Disclaimer: I haven't been able to find any good documentation for the Express Validator library and if someone has a link I can be more exact.

With this in mind, if the Express Validator library extends the Express `Request` interface, the definition should reflect this. Here is an example that extends the definitions for [Express and Express Validator on Definitely Typed](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped).

```
declare module Express {
    interface Request extends ExpressValidator.RequestValidation {

    }
}
```

This will solve the issues with `assert`, for example - if someone finds some documentation I expect the `validatonErrors` issue can be solved in a similar way.

Answer (score 1):

I have a helper `function` that checks for the `'id' param` on the `request` object. The declaration that works correctly on **TypeScript 1.5.0-beta** is:

```ts
// Somewhere at the top of your TypeScript code
/// <reference path="../../../../typings/tsd.d.ts" />
import ExpressValidator = require('express-validator');
import util = require('util');
```

And the helper function that I use:

```ts
function getOnePreconditions(req:ExpressValidator.RequestValidation, res:express.Response, next:Function) {
    req.checkParams('id', 'Parameter Id is mandatory').notEmpty().isInt();
    var errors = req.validationErrors();
    if (errors) {
        res.send(400, 'errors' + util.inspect(errors));
    } else {
        next();
    }
}
```

If you do have `tsd.json` defined for the project and you are correctly referencing to the `*.d.ts` **TypeScript** definition files in your code, then definitely add the declaration file for `express-validator` by using:

```
tsd install express-validator --save
```

Answer (score -1):

**You are doing it wrongly!**

You should define your validator middleware like this:

```
export const validate = (validations: any) => {
  return async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    for (const validation of validations) {
      const result = await validation.run(req);
      if (result.errors.length) break;
    }

    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if (errors.isEmpty()) {
      return next();
    }

    return res.status(400).json({
      status: 400,
      message: `Validation failed`,
      errors: errors.array(),
    });
  };
};
```

Then you will call it in your router as a middleware

```
// update company profile
router.put("/company/:id", otherMiddleware, validateSequential([
  body("businessName").isLength({ min: 3 }),
  body("registrationNumber").isLength({ min: 5 }),
  body("email").normalizeEmail().isEmail()
]), updateProfile);
```